# On a version of gradient descent

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to read [this paper](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/01/2527.pdf) and have gotten stuck. The author considers the problem of minimizing a convex function whose gradient has coordinate-wise Lipschitz constant $M$ (meaning that for all vectors $x$ and basis vectors $e_i$, we have $||f'(x+h e_i)-f'(x)||_2 \leq M|h|$) and considers the scheme 
$$ x(t+1) = x(t) - \frac{1}{M} [f'(x(t)]_k e_k$$ where $[\cdot]_i$ denotes the $i$'th entry of a vector and $k$ is the index which maximizes $|[f'(x(t)]_k|$. In words, we update by moving in the opposite direction of the largest component of the gradient.

The scheme is introduced on page 1 (see big box in middle of page) and just two lines later (in the sequence of inequalities after "Then,") the author appears to be using that $$ ||f'(x(t))||_2^2 \geq \frac{\left( f(x(t) - f(x^*) \right)^2}{||x(0) - x^*||_2^2}$$ where $f^*$ is the global minimum and $x^*$ is presumably the minimizer (I'm assuming - I see no definition for $x^*$).

Anyway, I don't see why this statement is true. I do see how to prove it if $x(0)$ were replaced by $x(t)$ on the right-hand side, so if it could be shown that $||x(t)-x^*||$ is nonincreasing, that would do it. But I don't see how to show that; it would seem to require showing  that $[f'(x(t))]_k$ has the same sign as $[x(t)-x^*]_k$, and I don't see how to argue that.

Comment: Ah, Nesterov. You have my sympathy. I suggest that you get a hold of his book, "Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization". Your answer is likely to be found in there. somewhere.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this, but is the very first inequality after "Then" (over-marked with "(1.2)") clear for everybody? I for one don't know how to prove it :(

Comment: @Sh3ljohn - one way to prove that claim is as follows. The fact that the gradient of $f$ has coordinate-wise Lipschitz constant $M$ implies that $$f(y) \leq f(x) + f'(x)^T (y-x) + \frac{M}{2} ||y-x||_2^2,$$ whenever $y-x$ is a multiple of some basis vector $e_i$. Plugging in $x(t+1)$ for $y$ and $x(t)$ for $x$ yields the desired inequality.

Comment: @robinson Thanks for your answer :) Now I understand. (_Note: The reference for this formula on Wikipedia refers to the lecture of Nesterov.. lol_)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130856/on-a-version-of-gradient-descent

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be differentiable and convex, with convex domain $\mathbb{D}$. Consider a point $x\in\mathbb{D}$. The linear approximation to $f$ at $x$ becomes:

$$\phi_x(y)=f(x)+\langle y-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle$$

We know that being convex, $f$ is larger than the linear approximation at any point. Hence we have:

\begin{align}
f(y) &\geq \phi_x(y) =f(x)+\langle y-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle\\
\langle x-y,\nabla f(x)\rangle &\geq f(x) - f(y)\\
\| y-x\| \cdot \| \nabla f(x)\| &\geq f(x) - f(y)
\end{align}

Simply let $y=x^*$ and rearrange to derive the inequality.